# equality for a measure $\mu(F\backslash E)= \mu(F)-\mu(E)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Studying for Real Analysis I encountered this exercise and I am a bit confused about it.

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,M)$, where $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. Show that if $E \subseteq F$ and $\mu(E)< \infty$ then $\mu(F\backslash E)= \mu(F)-\mu(E)$ (*). A statement like this means that if one side is finite then so is he other and they are equal.

(*) is pretty clear using countable additivity on $F\backslash E$ and $E$ since they are disjoint and their union gives $F$. I do not understand though why do we require that $\mu(E)< \infty$ ! Is it only not to have cases like $\infty - \infty$ in (**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: $\infty - \infty$ is meaningless and you want to avoid the situation when something meaningful, i.e. $\mu(F\setminus E)$, equals something meaningless.

You encounter the same situation when you define the integral of measurable function as $\int_X f\ d\mu := \int_X f^+\ d\mu - \int_X f^-\ d\mu$, *provided at least one of the two is finite*

Also, when you define a signed measure you want to ask that $\mu \colon \Sigma \to [-\infty,\infty)$ *or* $(-\infty,\infty]$.